# Disconnect tweepy stream

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, twitter, tweepy

I have created a global tweepy stream and I have one function where I want to disconnect it if it's active and after to start to track the word received as argument (with async=True). 
When I call the function for the first time it's working properly but after I receive errors. 
Here is the sequence where I m creating the stream:

```
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener = myStreamListener)
```

And here I use it:

```
def cauta_dupa_cuvant(word):
     myStream.disconnect()
     myStream.filter(languages=["en"], track = [word],is_async=True)
```

Any idea?

Comment: If it is working the first time but not subsequently I assume it's a scope issue. Also you shouldn't use `global` variable and always include the full error traceback. Another possibility is that it wasn't fully shutdown. You should instantiate a new Stream object and save that variable.

Comment: The function is a route and I m working on jupyter and problem is "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"